# ListAdapter and filter

Tags: android, listview, search, filter

I am trying to implement a simple listview based on strings. I followed this tutorial 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Now, I want to add a filter function but I did not find a simple way to do that.

The class ListViewAdapter gives the method getfilter() but not ListAdapter.

Can you help me out with that?

Regards.

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

    // albums JSONArray
    JSONArray hotels = null;

    // albums JSON url
    private static final String URL_HOTELS = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/slim/hotels";

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "hotel";

    ListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check for internet connection
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Hashmap for ListView
        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
        new LoadAlbums().execute();

        // get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        /**
         * Listview item click listener
         * TrackListActivity will be lauched by passing album id
         * */
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // on selecting a single album
                // TrackListActivity will be launched to show tracks inside the album
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleTrackActivity.class);

                // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
                String hotel_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("hotel_id", hotel_id);               

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });     

        TextView inputSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                //AlbumsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                Log.d("filter :",  cs.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                         
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all Albums by making http request
     * */
    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading hotels ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Albums JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json;

            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_HOTELS, "GET",
                        params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Hotels JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try {               
                hotels = new JSONArray(json);

                if (hotels != null) {
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < hotels.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = hotels.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        albumsList.add(map);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                     adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
                            R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name });

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `I am trying to implement a simple listview based on strings.` It looks that you are not as the tutorial is for a multilevel listview. Better try this one: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Answer (score 0):

just change `ListAdapter` to `SimpleAdapter` everything is still be the same but `filter` function :)

these work for me